# How can I center all text in the cells of the table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

The output of the following compiled code is not as expected. I want all text to be centered in the cell, so I need the text in the first and last columns to look like the other ones. How do I implement this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Conditions for Neutral Stability} 
\centering
   \begin{tabular}{|l||*{3}{M{4cm}|}}\hline
\backslashbox{Density}{Velocity}
&\makebox[3em]{$U_{1} < U_{2}$}&\makebox[3em]{$U_{1} = U_{2}$}&\makebox[3em]{$U_{1} > U_{2}$}
\\ [.5cm]\hline\hline
$\rho_{1}<\rho_{2}$ & Neutrally stable if \newline $|U_{1}-U_{2}|<\sqrt{\frac{g(\rho_{1}^{2}-\rho_{2}^{2})}{k\rho_{1}\rho_{2}}}$ &Unstable& Neutrally stable if $|U_{1}-U_{2}|<\sqrt{\frac{g(\rho_{1}^{2}-\rho_{2}^{2})}{k\rho_{1}\rho_{2}}}$\\ [1cm]\hline
$\rho_{1}=\rho_{2}$ &Unstable&Neutrally Stable&Unstable\\ [1cm]\hline
$\rho_{1}>\rho_{2}$ &Unstable&Unstable&Unstable\\ [1cm]\hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Compilation output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) Please describe your question as precise as possible!

Comment: Please tell us how the `M` type is defined.

Comment: Please rewrite your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077).

Comment: I edited the code to include the definition of M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
Since use of `diagbox` is mandatory, I accordingly change MWE in first version of answer. Let me noted, that now the table is wider and probably will not fit in text width. Some space (8mm) can be earned write equation in text style (drop command `\displaystyle` in complete MWE nelow} and change column width to:

```
   \begin{tabular}{|l||>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|
                        >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|
                        >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|}
```

[image]

I drop all options `[3em]` at `\makebox` and also replace `\\[1cm]` with `\\`. Instead lather I add `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}`, equations in second and third row write in `\displaystyle`, where I also ad some vertical space above and below of equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Conditions for Neutral Stability}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l||>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.4cm}|
                    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.0cm}|
                    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.4cm}|}
\hline
\backslashbox{Density}{Velocity}
    &   \makebox{$U_{1} < U_{2}$} 
        &   \makebox{$U_{1} = U_{2}$}
            &   \makebox{$U_{1} > U_{2}$}           \\
    \hline\hline

\rho_{1}<\rho_{2}   
    &   Neutrally stable if\smallskip\newline
        $\displaystyle
        |U_{1}-U_{2}|<
        \sqrt{\frac{g(\rho_{1}^{2}-\rho_{2}^{2})}{k\rho_{1}\rho_{2}}}
        $\smallskip
        &   Unstable    &   Neutrally stable if\smallskip\newline 
                            $\displaystyle
                            |U_{1}-U_{2}|<
                            \sqrt{\frac{g(\rho_{1}^{2}-
                                        \rho_{2}^{2})}{k\rho_{1}\rho_{2}}}
                            $\smallskip                              \\
    \hline
\rho_{1}=\rho_{2}
    &   Unstable        &   Neutrally Stable    &   Unstable                 \\
    \hline
\rho_{1}>\rho_{2}
    &   Unstable        &   Unstable            &   Unstable                 \\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Better look and small width of table can be achieved with use (i) `hhline` package, (ii) instead of `\backslashbox{Density}{Velocity}` use `\diagbox[innerwidth=2.4cm]{Density}{Velocity}}`, and shrinking third column to 1.8 cm. Also with insert `\diagbox` into curly braces all `\makebox{...}` become surplus:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Conditions for Neutral Stability}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c||>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.4cm}|
                        >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm}|
                        >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.4cm}|}
    \hhline{|-||-|-|-|}
{\diagbox[innerwidth=2.4cm]{Density}{Velocity}}
    &   $U_{1} < U_{2}$ 
        &   $U_{1} = U_{2}$
            &   $U_{1} > U_{2}$            \\
    \hhline{:=::=:=:=:}
$\rho_{1}<\rho_{2}$   
    &   Neutrally stable if\smallskip\newline
        $\displaystyle
        |U_{1}-U_{2}|<
        \sqrt{\frac{g(\rho_{1}^{2}-\rho_{2}^{2})}{k\rho_{1}\rho_{2}}}
        $\smallskip
        &   Unstable    &   Neutrally stable if\smallskip\newline 
                            $\displaystyle
                            |U_{1}-U_{2}|<
                            \sqrt{\frac{g(\rho_{1}^{2}-
                                        \rho_{2}^{2})}{k\rho_{1}\rho_{2}}}
                            $\smallskip                              \\
    \hhline{|-||-|-|-|}
$\rho_{1}=\rho_{2}$
    &   Unstable        &   Neutrally Stable    &   Unstable                 \\
    \hhline{|-||-|-|-|}
$\rho_{1}>\rho_{2}$
    &   Unstable        &   Unstable            &   Unstable                 \\
    \hhline{|-||-|-|-|}
   \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zarko! But I actually need it in the format above, with the split cell and the double horizontals and everything. The only thing I need changed is the centering of the text within the cells. If you have any help on that, that'd be great!

Comment: meanwhile i resolve issue with `diagbox` and its macro `\backslashbox`, see if now the result is as you like to have.

Comment: @OAM, to my answer I add new possible solution.

Comment: if you liked solution and it help you, you can accept answer (click on check mark at top left side of answer :) )